# python: how to easily display blinking filled circle

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, python-turtle

I am new to python. I am trying to get a blining red circle (indicator) if my vpn tunnel is down and steady green if my vpn is up.However, where i am currently stuck is in building this blinking red light.

I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import turtle

turtle.setup(100,150)

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.speed(0)
while True:
    #Python program to draw color filled circle in turtle programming
    t.begin_fill()
    t.fillcolor('red')
    t.circle(25)
    t.end_fill()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.fillcolor('white')
    t.circle(25)
    t.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

and it is almost there, except that it takes a "long" time to draw the circle. Is there any other better way out of this? Btw, is it possible to get a transparent background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
import time

WHITE =     (255, 255, 255)
RED =       (255,   0,   0)
(width, height) = (40, 40)

background_color = WHITE

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("VPN-Status")
screen.fill(background_color)
pygame.display.update()

while True:
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (20, 20), 20)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.25)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, (20, 20), 20)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.25)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fiddle with the [turtle.speed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.speed) command.

setting `t.speed(0)` results in a fast blink.

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer: it should be `t.speed(0)`

Comment: Sorry, my error. It works.Thanks! Uodated wth the correction.But it does slow down after a while which is OK, unless it will become slower and hog more resources.

Comment: sorry, but it becomes slower and slower.

Comment: Oh. I am not sure why it would be the case, that may be related to how turtle manages fills (that is not a trivial task, you have to compute the area enclosed by the turtle path). 
You might want to consider another drawing library in this case, that posses direct circle drawing primitives (turtle does not seem to fit your use case). Do you know about [pygame](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try a different approach, using an `ontimer()` event to control flashing speed and blinking a circular turtle instead of redrawing every time:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def blink():
    pen, fill = turtle.color()
    turtle.color(fill, pen)
    screen.ontimer(blink, 250)  # 1/4 second blink

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('circle')
turtle.shapesize(50 / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.color('red', 'white')
turtle.showturtle()

blink()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thanks, so, which one is better? turltle or pygame? it seems to slow down a bit eventually. I guess I should run it for days to see.

Comment: @user3236841, neither is better, they're just different environments with different goals.  Your particular problem falls into their overlap.  I'm surprised it still slows down but if you require more precise blinking over time, you might consider dropping down a level to tkinter, atop which turtle sits.

Comment: Can you give me a reference on how to do this using tkinter? Thanks!